# What is the Correct Way to Reference a Firebase Database on Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on my first project using Firebase Real time database. I'm following the Firebase docs on how to instantiate and write to a database (no problem here). However, when I want to read data from the Firebase database, I get a null reference to my database. I've trying changing the path, adding root element, changing to a child element. Nothing works. I can write to it. My permissions for the db are set for testing.

This is the database:

```
user-registration-app-f3fa2
 users
  jjohnson
     email:"jjohnson@parks.org"
     fullName: "James Johnson"
     username: "jjohnson"
```

This is where I read from database:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference mDatabase = database.getReference("users");

        // Read from the database
        mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String value = dataSnapshot.child("jvazquez").getValue(String.class);
                Log.d(TAG, "Value is: " + value);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                // Failed to read value
                Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value of `fullName` property for example, please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference fullNameRef = rootRef.child("users").child("jjohnson").child("fullName");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String fullName = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        Log.d(TAG, fullName);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
fullNameRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The output in the logcat will be:

```
James Johnson
```

Comment: alright I think I found the issue... in a different class I have this database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mDatabase = database.getReference(USERS); and mDatabase is not returning null... why?

Comment: A `DatabaseReference` object that is initialized will never return `null`. Have you tried my solution above, does it work?

Comment: it works... now why my reference which I got from firebase documentation works in one class and not the other (the exact same ref) beats me

Comment: I guess is because it is not correctly initialized. Good to hear that is worked ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase = database.getReference();
```

And then try

```
mDatabase = mDatabase.child("users");
```

Comment: my mDatabase is returning null... I'm not properly referencing my db. I run debugger and at line 2 of my code above I get null when instantiating mDatabase. database is returning a reference but not mDatabase

Comment: Did you configure permission in Firebase?

Comment: is in testing mode {
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}

Comment: Also did you try `database.getReference().child("users")`?

Comment: which one return null `database.getReference()` or `mDatabase.child("users")`?

Comment: alright I think I found the issue... in a different class I have this database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(); mDatabase = database.getReference(USERS); and mDatabase is not returning null... why? – miatech 5 secs ago   Edit   Delete

Comment: I should be able to reference database from more than one class

Comment: I have a regisration class and  userProfile class. registration class reference to db works just fine, but not in userProfile returns null. user profile is for displaying user data